# TypeError: (0, _reactNative.useColorScheme) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to useuseColorScheme hook in my react native functional component.

But I am getting this below error when I add below line

const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

TypeError: (0, _reactNative.useColorScheme) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNative.useColorScheme)()', '(0, _reactNative.useColorScheme)' is undefined)

my react native version is 0.60.5

Comment: Are you importing useColorScheme correclty?

Comment: Hi @user3812411
I am importing like this
import {
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  useColorScheme
} from 'react-native';

Comment: useColorScheme were introduced in 0.62